# [siddhi]How Can I use siddhi stream in multi files

Tags: siddhi

I met a problem when I use siddhi, the problem is that I have too much streams in one .siddhi file.The siddhql looks terrible and it's hard to mainten. Does Anyone know how can I put siddhi streams in diffrent siddhi files? And these streams in diffrent files still can send info to stream in other file.Please help.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Inmemory source and sinks to send events between two different siddhi files i.e two different siddhi app runtimes,
https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/api/latest/#inmemory-source

```
@sink(type='inMemory', topic='Stocks', @map(type='passThrough'))
define stream StocksStream (symbol string, price float, volume long);
```

The above sends out to the specific topic

```
@source(type='inMemory', topic='Stocks', @map(type='passThrough'))
define stream StocksStream (symbol string, price float, volume long);
```

The above receives from specific topic

Comment: Thanks a lot，I saw the siddhi docs, it should work, you have my thanks!